# Openshift 3 Starter failed to push image

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-3, openshift-online

I tried to previously successfully built projects and both got the same error message:

> error: build error: Failed to push image: Get
>   https://docker-registry.default.svc:5000/v1/_ping:  x509: certificate
>   is valid for
>   docker-registry-default.xxxx.starter-us-west-2.openshiftapps.com,
>   docker-registry.default.svc.cluster.local, 172.xx.xx.xx, not
>   docker-registry.default.svc

Comment: Are you saying this worked for the application before and has just started? Does it happen every time if trigger new builds? The status does say that cluster is currently going through an upgrade, so there is a chance that during that certain things such as builds and new deployments may not work for short periods of time. Existing running applications should be unaffected. https://status.starter.openshift.com/

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton okay so I will try again tomorrow. Thx.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton yeah even the sample project failed.

Comment: Same here with us-west 15:22 GMT. I had build problems earlier with pushing images, but these were related due to server outage and later healed. However I have never experienced this exact kind of error.

Comment: @sbtpr it seems to create error messages still but my deployment is up now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are refering to the registry service by a name that is not included in the certificate for it. `docker-registry.default.svc` you should use something like `docker-registry.default.svc.cluster.local` instead to match name supported by certificate

Comment: Where can I modify the certificate? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AeroWang did you find out where to change this as I am being stung by this issue at the moment and there is very little info online on the subject.

Comment: @Grofit nothing needed to be changed. I simply waited three days and now it works.

Comment: Amazing... what a service

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they have reverted some of the changes made yesterday. It works good now.

Comment: Build succeeded 20:54 GMT. But the deploy still fails. Short popup message talks about replicacontroller missing.